# How to ion-button justify-content?

Tags: css, ionic4

I have the following code:

```
<ion-button expand=“full” (click)=“do()“>
  <ion-icon name=“cart” slot=“start”></ion-icon>
  TEXT
</ion-button>
```

I want the content (the TEXT and the ion-icon) to be aligned to the left and tried:

```
ion-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

I thought this would result into aligning the content to the left but nothing happens. It seems that the css is totally ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can align the text and icon to the left if you add a div inside your button and use Ionic 4 CSS Utilities (in your case text-left / text-start).

```
<ion-button expand=“full” (click)=“do()“>
 <div text-left>
  <ion-icon name=“cart” slot=“start”></ion-icon>
  TEXT
 </div>
</ion-button>
```

Make sure to give the div the full width of the button

```
ion-button > div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Documentation:
[Ionic 4 CSS Utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities)

Comment: awesome. didn't expect something like this … thank you Tomas!

Comment: @Kai-SebastianBirkenstock happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your inner in `span` and add in css

```
  .inner-span{
    margin-left:auto;
  }
```

As below (use `"` instead `“`)

```
<ion-button expand="full" (click)="do()">
  <span class="inner-span">            
   <ion-icon name="cart" slot="start"></ion-icon>
   TEXT
  </span> 
</ion-button>
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-template-2cn81q?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 5 I wanted to use `expand="block"` *and* justify the text left and the icon right plus override the text styles so I was able to do this based on the previous answers:

```
<ion-button color="light" expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="logout()">
    <div class="justify-content-space-between">
        <span class="nav-title">{{ 'app.menu.item.logout.label'|text }}</span>
        <ion-icon class="mr-16" slot="end" ios="log-out-outline" md="log-out-sharp"></ion-icon>
    </div>
</ion-button>
```

```
ion-button {
    .justify-content-space-between {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
    }

    &::part(native) {
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: none;   
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ionic 5 and i did like this, put a span inside a button with text inside and then style as follows:

```css
ion-button{
  span{
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-button expand="block">
 <ion-icon slot="start" name="add-outline" ></ion-icon>
 <span>Add</span>
</ion-button>
```